# How to link two GTM tags (for two separate domains) into the same google ads account

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-ads-api

The conversion flow of one of our google ads campaign begins on one domain and ends in another domain. In order to send the conversion data back to google ads, do I need the GTM account on the second domain to also be linked to Google ads, and if so how do I go about doing it?

As of now, I have the GTM account of the first domain linked to google ads. Yet to figure out how to link the second GTM account or, if there is another way to send data back to google ads.